# Total in progress time in JIRA

Tags: jira, jql, time-tracking

guys could you please advice how to make a report which contains total "in progress" time for certain task using JQL or any other JIRA methods?

Is it possible without using additional plugins?

Thx

Comment: "Total in progress" what? Number of tasks? The sum of remaining time for all those issues? What?

Comment: Sorry, of course total "in progress" **time** for certain task

Answer (score 0):

This question was actually asked here before.

The answer unfortunately is no - JIRA on itself does not provide such functionality.
You can however implement a plug-in or an external service that tracks this.
The idea would be that when an issue makes the transition to "In Progress" a trigger is fired and your plug-in or external service begins to track the "total in progress time".

You will also have the case for when an issue goes from "In Progress" to "On Hold" (for example) and then back to "In Progress". This is fairly easy logic to implement.

Another thing to do is to file an RFC with Atlassian on their support web site and ask for this as a feature. People have already asked there and the more people ask - the sooner they will implement this in the system.

Comment: Bad news... thanks for information. 
Although if you look on task (when using kanban dashboard) there are small dots colored from light grey to dark grey. If you place a cursor on them you will see hint message "this task was N days in this column".
Why didn't they make a report I don't know :)

Comment: Head over to the Atlassian support site - ask.atlassian.com . They may know!

Answer (score 0):

this functions is an enhancement for Jira which is unfortunately marked as "won't fix". you may use the [aggregations](https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GRV/Scripted+JQL+Functions#ScriptedJQLFunctions-AggregateExpressions) to suit part of your need.